# Content clause : Wh-interrogative clause & Nominal relative clause

Tags: meaning, grammar, differences, ambiguity, clauses

**Wh-interrogative clauses** and **nominal relative clauses** are two types of **content clauses**. Both of them are introduced by a *wh-element* & they look so similar that it's often difficult to distinguish them.
For example,

> 1. I can't imagine *what they want with your address*. [ Wh-interrigatove clause]
> 2. I took *what they offered me*. [Nominal relative clause]
> 3. *How the book will sell* depends on the reviewers. [Wh-interrogative clause]
> 4. *What happened* upset him. [Nominal relative clause]

Is it possible to distinguish these two types of content clauses (Nominal clauses)?

Comment: In (1), there is an **underlying question**. "What do they want with your address?" ... It has an answer (at least notionally). ... 'I' can't imagine what the answer is. / In (3), the underlying question is '"How well will the book sell?" The answer will doubtless be revealed. We can say beforehand that the answer is partly dependent on the efforts of the publishers. // There are no underlying questions in (2) and (4); 'what' = 'the thing / proposal / offer etc.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you. But sometimes we can find underlying question in a nominal relative clause too. For example, What can you open the bottle with? ... the answer is in this sentence : "I 'll show you what you can open the bottle with." (Nominal relative clause as prepositional complement).

Comment: Again, "They did not consult us on whose name should be put forward". (Wh-interrogatove clause as prepositional complement). Aren't they difficult to distinguish?

Comment: In "What can you open the bottle with?" the question is overt. In your next sentence, The 'preposition + wh-clause' is surely a third form?